# Intense data processing prevents UI interaction from taking effect

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch, lag

I'm doing intense data processing in an iOS app and I have a "cancel" `UIButton`. The user can press the cancel button, but since the app is so laggy from the processing, the click usually doesn't get recognized for about 10 seconds. Yet I can click the home button on my device and the phone instantly goes to the home screen.

I'm assuming the home button is programmed by Apple to have top level priority. Is there any way I can make the cancel button within the app have "top priority", above laggy animation and screen UI updating and laggy data processing? I'm assuming this will have something to do with GCD - Dispatch levels?

Comment: you can give low priority (`DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND`) for data processing tasks

Comment: Please post the code where you start your background process and the code where you cancel it.  You cannot raise the priority of your UI (it will always run on the main thread).

Comment: Are you already using GCD (or similar) to put your processing in the background? If not, do that.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm using GCD for a few things. Most of our data processing involves communicating with a server (Uploading math equation images), the loading time for uploading our Latex HD images is around 10 seconds... Will putting this code in a background thread or low priority thread affect upload time or server communication? I know very little about GCD and what operations are and aren't allowed in it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The main queue is used for all the main UI interactions and animation. It sounds like you are doing your data processing on the main thread too. This may not be the path you want to take but you might consider moving your data processing task to a separate thread with GCD as opposed to trying to get the UIButton to get a higher priority.